# Generic interface with equals and hashCode methods, is it possible?

Tags: java

I'd like to define an interface that will be used to implement keys for a map. The map uses equals and hasCode to locate and compare keys. My keys need to override these with custom computations. Here is what I'd like to do. It's important that the complex key is used. Thanks

```
public interface CachedRequestKey<T>{
    public T complexKeyObject;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(T obj);

}
```

EDIT for down voters: I'm aware the above code is not valid. I'm looking for ideas to achieve an interface that insures the implementing class provides required methods using the generic type.

Comment: Interfaces do not contain implementation by default, and cannot represent additional object state. Maybe you would like a decorator class for key objects instead? Please clarify.

Comment: Your `equals` method does not correctly override `Object#equals` and thus won't work like you expect.

Comment: You could wrap the objects and keep the additional state there.  Collection classes won't use custom equals/hashCode methods, unless the Collection is defined in terms of a Comparator (like TreeMap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want isn't possible in Java.  Object already implements `equals` and `hashCode`, so every subclass does automatically as well.  There's no way for an interface or abstract class to require it to be reimplemented.  It's assumed that `equals` and `hashCode` for a given class are implemented correctly for that class.

If you really need your classes to implement specific comparison operations and don't want to use the existing equality methods by accident, you could define your own comparison functions on you interface and require implementing classes to define those.  Classes that already implement your equality mechanics in their equals and hashCode methods can delegate to the existing methods.